# Spyder Matplotlib RuntimeError: dvipng was not able to process the following file

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

This following problem seems to occur only on Spyder IDE, it does not occur when I run the script from the command line.

Trying to make a simple plot using pyplot with Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)|:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x,y)
```

I got the following message:

```
sh: 1: dvipng: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 176, in __draw_idle_agg
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 474, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1159, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2324, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1111, in draw
    tick.draw(renderer)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 252, in draw
    self.label1.draw(renderer)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 792, in draw
    mtext=mtext)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 253, in draw_tex
    Z = texmanager.get_grey(s, size, self.dpi)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 583, in get_grey
    pngfile = self.make_png(tex, fontsize, dpi)
  File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 524, in make_png
    'dvipng: \n\n' % dvifile + report)
RuntimeError: dvipng was not able to process the following file:
/home/ohm/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/d0e4b65f3cbceaa40d39cd0b4aa94322.dvi
Here is the full report generated by dvipng:
```

Somebody knows what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure first `dvipng` is installed outside spyder. This can be done as follows. On a unix system (Mac OSX, LInux), please go to the terminal, and enter

```
which dvipng
```

(a similar command is available in the Windows power shell). This command will either

1. Return an error, in which case you must first install `dvipng`, with a procedure that depends exquisitely on your operative system

or

2. Return a path, for example `/usr/bin/texlive/dvipng` (the exact path may vary).

If 1., install `dvipng`. This may solve your issue. If not, please go to the start of the instructions. If you have installed `dvipng`, you will end up in 2.

If 2., then from within `spyder`

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += ':/usr/bin/texlive'
```

This will make `python` aware of the command `dvipng`. Please excuse the delay in responding to this question.